# issue using .hide() when passing a variable from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works fine:

```
 $(function mvp() {
    var theMvp = ['#mvpWtd', '#mvpStd'];
    $.each(theMvp, function (index, value) {
        $(value + ' .budTySales').hide();
        $(value + ' .lySales').hide();
        $(value + ' .budReceipts').hide();
        $(value + ' .lyReceipts').hide();
    });
})
```

According to jquery documentation I should be able to pass multiple elements in followed by a comma instead of doing it line by line (less code too!). I tried changing my code to the below but it fails...

```
$(function mvp() {
    var theMvp = ['#mvpWtd', '#mvpStd'];
    $.each(theMvp, function (index, value) {
        $(value + ' .budTySales',value + ' .lySales',value + ' .budReceipts',value + ' .lyReceipts').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: You are wrongly concatening string here. Commas should be part of former string. Anyway, you would have better to use `$(theMvp.toString()).find('.budTySales, .lySales, .budReceipts, .lyReceipts').hide();` or better **just use a specific common class**...

Comment: thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
$(value + ' .budTySales',value + ' .lySales',value + ' .budReceipts',value + ' .lyReceipts').hide();
```

should be:

```
$(value + ' .budTySales,' + value + ' .lySales,' + value + ' .budReceipts,' + value + ' .lyReceipts').hide();
```

Notice that the commas are inside the quotes. This is because jQuery expects a single parameter to be passed into it, not multiple, which is what you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, comma should be part of the string.

`$(value + ' .budTySales, ' +  value + ' .lySales, ' + value + ' .budReceipts, '+ value + ' .lyReceipts').hide();` should work